# Modify a prototype function from a different module

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, commonjs

Say I want to write a plugin, a module that modifies the object exported in a different module. How do I modify one of the methods of the original object? Here's the code I'm trying to get to work. There's something fundamental I feel that I'm missing here.

**server.js**

```
var Fun = require('./fun2');

var fun = new Fun('honey');
console.log(fun.allTheBest(3));
fun.hiccup();
```

**fun.js**

```
var Fun = function(b) {
    this.best = b;

    this.allTheBest = function(n) {
        var theBest = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            theBest += this.best + ' ';
        }
        return theBest;
    };
};

module.exports = Fun;
```

**fun2.js**

```
var Fun = require('./fun');

var oldAllTheBest = Fun.prototype.allTheBest;

Fun.allTheBest = function (n) {
    console.log("I'm starting allTheBest.");
    return oldAllTheBest.apply(this, n);
};

Fun.prototype.hiccup = function() {
    console.log('Hic!');
};

module.exports = Fun;
```

And this is the output I get:

```
honey honey honey 
Hic!
```

But I expected this:

```
I'm starting allTheBest.
honey honey honey
Hic!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three problems in your code. First, as pointed by Bergi, you should overwrite the prototype function like this:

```
Fun.prototype.allTheBest = function(n) { /* ... */ }
```

Secondly, when you try to get the old definition of `allTheBest` in `var oldAllTheBest = Fun.prototype.allTheBest;` you will get `undefined`. That's because the definition of `allTheBest` in `fun.js` will only be created when you instantiate the `Fun` object via `new`. You should define the function via `prototype` instead:

**`fun.js`**

```
var Fun = function(b) {
    this.best = b;
}

Fun.prototype.allTheBest = function(n) {
        var theBest = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            theBest += this.best + ' ';
        }
        return theBest;
};

module.exports = Fun;
```

And lastly, you are calling `apply` incorrectly. `apply` takes an array of parameters.

So you either change your code to this:

```
return oldAllTheBest.apply(this, [n]);
```

or this:

```
return oldAllTheBest.call(this, n);
```

With these changes, your script will have the desired output:

```
victor@ubuntu:~/Documents/a$ node app.js 
I'm starting allTheBest.
honey honey honey 
Hic!
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> var oldAllTheBest = Fun.prototype.allTheBest;
> Fun.allTheBest = function (n) {
> ```

You'll want to overwrite

```
Fun.prototype.allTheBest = function(n) {
```